# When using do() on the output of do(), how to keep the same list structure for rowwise() data frame and group_by() dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have function that computes a model for various products and another function that formats the result. I use them in two steps:

1. group the data frame by product (and potentially by another variable) and use do() to create a data frame containing model output for each product.
2. use do() again to create a data frame of formatted results.

The issue is that my formatting function used in step 2 will see different input format depending on whether or not the data frame is grouped rowwise() or group_by(). Here is a reproducible example where you can look at the output of str():

### Step 1:

```
mockmodel <- function(dtf){
    list(a = mean(dtf$Petal.Length),
         b = as.character(unique(dtf$Species)))
}
iris2 <- iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    do(x = mockmodel(.))
```

### Step 2.

```
formatoutput <- function(dtf){
    data.frame(aisinthere = !is.null(dtf$x[[1]]$a),
               meanpetallength = dtf$x[[1]]$a)
}
```

#### on rowwise() data frame

Gives an error

```
iris2 %>% do(formatoutput(.)) 

Error in dtf$x[[1]]$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

#### on group_by() data frame

Works but gives a warning.

```
iris2 %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(formatoutput(.)) 

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: Species

     Species aisinthere meanpetallength
1     setosa       TRUE           1.462
2 versicolor       TRUE           4.260
3  virginica       TRUE           5.552
Warning message:
Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature
```

### Data structure

```
strx <- function(dtf){
    str(dtf$x) # display structure
    data.frame() # make do happy
}
iris2 %>% do(strx(.))

List of 2
 $ a: num 1.46
 $ b: chr "setosa"
List of 2
 $ a: num 4.26
 $ b: chr "versicolor"
List of 2
 $ a: num 5.55
 $ b: chr "virginica"
Source: local data frame [0 x 0]
Groups: <by row>

iris2 %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(strx(.))

List of 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: num 1.46
  ..$ b: chr "setosa"
List of 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: num 4.26
  ..$ b: chr "versicolor"
List of 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: num 5.55
  ..$ b: chr "virginica"
Source: local data frame [0 x 1]
Groups: Species

Variables not shown: Species (fctr)
Warning message:
Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature
```

The output of str() tells us that the structure of dtf$x is different when do() is used with `group_by()` than when do is used after `rowwise()`. How to avoid this and use the same function for data frames grouped using `rowwise()` and those grouped using `group_by(Species, another_variable)`?
My current workaround consists of always using `group_by()` again before the second do() operation. In fact to avoid the warning about "strip rowwise nature", I even use `ungroup() %>% group_by(item)` before the second do() operation. Is there a better way?

This part of the  dplyr::do() documentation may be relevant. It specifies that the output of the first do() is grouped rowwise() by default:

> "Groups are preserved for a single unnamed input. This is different to
>   summarise because do generally does not reduce the complexity of the
>   data, it just expresses it in a special way. For multiple named
>   inputs, the output is grouped by row with rowwise. This allows other
>   verbs to work in an intuitive way."